# VoiceXML won't send recording to submit next

Tags: php, vxml, voicexml, vonage

I have this VoiceXML script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version = "2.1" >
  <form>
    <record name="recording" beep="true" dtmfterm="true" maxtime="100s">
      <prompt>
        This is the message recording system.
      </prompt>
      <prompt>
        Please start your recording at the sound of the beep.
      </prompt>
      <prompt>
        After you are finished, you may press any key to indicate that you are done recording.
      </prompt>
      <filled>
        <prompt>
          Your recording was <value expr="recording" /> The message has been saved, you can now sent it from your control panel. Thanks!
        </prompt>
        <submit next="https://myserver/saveMessage.php" method="post" namelist="recording" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
      </filled>
    </record>
  </form>
</vxml>
```

Everything in the script seems to be working ok, all the prompts are read, the recording plays fine with , but saveMessage.php on my server is never touched (I put a log at the top of saveMessage.php which fires when I visit saveMessage.php in my browser, but never fires when I make a call to my VoiceXML script).

Am I missing something easy? Can VoiceXML scripts not submit next to a server they aren't on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue where my phone provider (http://nexmo.com) was not trusting my comodo signed SSL certificate. I sent them to http myserver/saveMessage.php instead of https and it "fixed" the issue (until I get a new certificate).